# Read from file inside Eclipse Project

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

I want to make an application that splits a big text file inside `inputfolder` into several small XML files to be put inside `outputfolder`.

This is project outline:

[image]

The following code works fine when it comes to getting a file from an outside folder, but when I modified it to read from a folder inside the project, it gave me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.zakaria.cut.XmlCutter.cut(XmlCutter.java:45)
at com.zakaria.cut.Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

[XmlCutter.java]

```
package com.zakaria.cut;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler;
import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class XmlCutter {

 private static final String OUTPUT_FILE_NAME = "/file";
 //private static String USER_HOME = System.getProperty("user.home");
 private static final String INPUT_FOLDER = "../inputfolder";
 private static String OUTPUT_FOLDER = "../outputfolder";
 private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger("XmlCutter");
 private static long COUNTER = 0;

 public XmlCutter() {
super();
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void cut() {
  Handler h = new ConsoleHandler();
  h.setLevel(Level.FINE);
  LOG.addHandler(h);
  LOG.setLevel(Level.FINE);

  File inputDir = new File(INPUT_FOLDER);
  File[] filesInInputDir = inputDir.listFiles();
  for (File f : filesInInputDir) {
   if ((f.getName()).endsWith(".txt")) {
    LOG.fine((MessageFormat.format(
      "Found a text file {0}. Processing docs...",
      f.getName())));
    processFile(f);
   }
  }
 }

 private static void processFile(File f) {
  StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
  char prev = '#';
  try {
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
     new FileInputStream(f), "UTF8"));
   char[] buf = new char[1];
   while (br.read(buf) >= 0) {
    out.append(buf[0]);
    if (prev == '<' && buf[0] == '?') {
     LOG.finest((MessageFormat.format(
       "Start of XML PI Found: {0}{1}", prev, buf[0])));
     if (out.length() > 2) {
      flushToFile(out.substring(0, out.length() - 2));
     }
     out.setLength(2);
    }
    prev = buf[0];
   }
   LOG.finest("Writing final file");
   flushToFile(out.toString());
   br.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   LOG.fine(e.getMessage());
  }
  LOG.fine(MessageFormat.format("Generated {0} XML Documents", COUNTER));
 }

 private static void flushToFile(String s) {
  File f = new File(OUTPUT_FOLDER + OUTPUT_FILE_NAME + (++COUNTER)
    + ".xml");
  LOG.finest(MessageFormat.format("Writing file: {0}", f.getName()));
  try {
   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
   OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF8");
   osw.write(s);
   osw.flush();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   LOG.fine(e.getMessage());
  }
 }
}
```

[Main.java]

```
package com.zakaria.cut;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        XmlCutter cutter = new XmlCutter();
        cutter.cut();
    }
}
```

The problem, I guess, is definitely here:

```
 private static final String INPUT_FOLDER = "../inputfolder";
 private static String OUTPUT_FOLDER = "../outputfolder";
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what folder the program is executing from? My guess is the relative links are pointing to the wrong spot? Have you tried hard coding the paths and see if they work? If they do you might have to look at the your execution folder and then change the relative paths accordingly?

Comment: The file I want to read is in `com.zakaria.cut.inputfolder` and the result files will be saved in `com.zakaria.cut.outputfolder` .
Check the outline picture.

Comment: But isn't the default working directory when you execute the program `XML-Parser-Test` and your relative path is pointing to a folder outside of that structure? `../` means the folder one level up from the current working directory. At least this is how I am reading your hierarchy.

Comment: I actually found the solution, instead of having `../inputfolder` I wrote `src/com/zakaria/cut/inputfolder` and it worked perfectly.
Thanks for your help @Scott